# Salvar dados de formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html, formulário

Gente, sou novo nisso, fiz um formulário em html e n consigo salvar os dados, como faço isso?

Comment: Bem vindo Fagner, pra que a comunidade possa te ajudar é importante que vc detalhe mais a sua pergunta, coloque como seu código está até agora.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente você vai criar o formulário:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <label>Nome:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <label>Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <label>Senha:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Na `action.php`:

```
<?php 
    $meuBancoDeDados='nome do seu banco de dados';
    $username='nome do usuário de acesso ao banco de dados';
    $password='senha do usuário de acesso ao banco de dados';

    // Aqui será criada uma conexão com o banco de dados, estou usando PDO para isso
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$meuBancoDeDados, $username, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    // Aqui são definidas as variáveis vindas do formulário
    $nome=$_POST["name"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];

    // Aqui é executado a inserção no banco de dados
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO minhaTabela (nome,email,password) VALUES(:nome,:email,:password)');
    $stmt->bindParam(":nome",$nome);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email",$email);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password",$password);
    if($stmt->execute()):
        echo "Inserido";
    else:
        echo "Erro ao inserir";
    endif;
?>
```

Lembrando que isso é apenas um esboço simples, todos as entradas devem ser tratadas para evitar ataques, etc.

**Sempre buscar estudar e aprender mais sobre a linguagem que será usada e entender as funções**

> [Manual - PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)
>
> [Entendendo a classe PDO - Médium](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/entendendo-e-utilizando-a-classe-pdo-836b3fcaf75)

Comment: O formulário esta sem método. POST / GET

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar a action na tag `<form>`, e dentro dele vai colocar um input com o `type submit`. Esse input será o botão de enviar o formulário

Conforme o exemplo da w3school
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: E oq eu coloco no arquivo php?